# Move right and return on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move table element right on $(window).scrollTop > 200 and return it back when $(window).scrollTop < 200 but it want return back.

```
//On scroll 
    var scrollTop;
    var scroll_down = false;
    var prevScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > prevScroll) {
            scroll_down = true;
        } else {
            scroll_down = false;
        }           
        if (scroll_down & scrollTop > 100) {
            $('.home table').animate({'right': '-100%'}, 500);
        } else if (!scroll_down & scrollTop < 100) {
            $('.home table').animate({'right': '10%'}, 500);        
        }
        prevScroll = scrollTop;
    });
```

Comment: one "&" is "binary bitwise and", two ("&&") is "boolean and", which is more likely what you're looking for (though in this case it doesn't make a difference I believe); eg. `1 & 2 -> 0b01 & 0b10 -> 0b00 -> 0 -> false`; `1 && 2 -> true && true -> true`

Comment: Use `...).stop().animate(......`

Answer (score 0):

**<sup>[1]</sup>** You need to use [**`.stop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before `.animate(` to stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

**<sup>[2]</sup>** In your case no need to check for down/up scroll while you only want the animate to fire for specific `scrollTop()` 100 or 200

```js
//On scroll 
let prev = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var Right = $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? "-100%" : "10%"; // get the `right` value 
  if(prev !== Right){
    $('.home table').stop().animate({'right': prev = Right}, 500); // animate
  }
});
```

```css
.home{height : 2000px;}
.home table{position : fixed;top : 0;width : 100%;background : red;height : 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

<sup>Also as @Leonard suggested in the comment below you can use `prev` variable with `if` condition</sup>

> To remove the "glichyness", only start the animation when necessary;

Comment: To remove the "glichyness", only start the animation when necessary: `let prev = 0;
    $(window).scroll(()=> {
      const v = $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? "-100%" : "10%";
      if (prev != v) $('.home table').stop().animate({'right': (prev = v)}, 500);
    });`

Comment: Thanks, you're right! But I need to check scroll up/down cause I need to do that animation for more elements. But this is answer! @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: You're totally welcome @JovanBelanov .. Have a nice day :-)